# setText() in android showing garbage values

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have an `activity` where I have two `textViews` , and I have applied `setText()` method on both these `textViews`. The code is shown below :

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView text1,text2;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        text1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
        text2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text2);

        text1.setText(R.string.display+" text");
        text2.setText("Display"+" text");
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.shaloin.settext.MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**strings.xml**

```
 <string name="display">Display : </string>
```

The problem here is that the first `textView` shows `2131099682 text` and the second `textView` shows `Display text`. I am not able to understand why this is happening.

Also, if I change `text1.setText(R.string.display+" text");` to 
`text1.setText(R.string.display);` , I get a normal output which is `Display`. Can anyone please clear my doubt.I have attached an image which shows the output. Thank you :)

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T77Z6.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`R.string.display` is actually a numeric ID, this is what you are seeing. What you have to use instead is `getString(R.string.display)`

By using the ID alone, setText knows that you passed in an integer and resolves the string itself. But if you add a string behind, then setText thinks it's a string and outputs it just as it gets it.

Comment: why doesn't  `text1.setText(R.string.display);`  show any garbage value?

Comment: It is because the method setText can take either the ID or a string. If you pass the ID alone, it finds the string. What you were doing was `R.string.display+" text"` so instead of passing (let's say) 1232123 to the function, you pass "1232123 text" which is a string and now the function just outputs the string as it is.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be getting the context of the app.

textViewID.setText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.display + "something else if you want");

I like to create a method that takes in an int and then I make it look nicer by doing textViewID.setText(method(R.id.display) + "something else if you want");

The reason why textViewID.setText(R.string.display) doesnt work is because that is actually an int value (the R.string.display). Plus you need to get the value of that resource.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the String value from resources directly into Activity. You need to get those with the resources object. Currently you are getting the value like this:

```
text1.setText(R.string.display+" text");
```

Change it to:

```
text1.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.display) + " text");
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: Thank you for the explanation :)